# Android Studio update from 3.6.2 to 3.6.3 fails, conflict with idea.jar

Tags: android-studio

I have been using Android Studio v3.6.2 for a while:

[image]

Today I tried to update to v3.6.3 but was foiled by this error:

[image]

I have never added any extra packages or plugins, this is a completely stock installation of Android Studio. So I have no clue what idea.jar is, where it came from, what it does, or how to get rid of it.

Any tips about how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow this was fixed after rebooting the computer.